# How to use sort and copy commands with pipes concept?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have been using this command to make a file "results" with the output of the command "ls" in the sorted manner.

> ls | sort | < results

But,I have find out that the file "results" is empty even though the "ls" command shows many files and folders.

Can some please explain the fault in using this command to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your redirection is in the wrong direction, use `>` instead of `<`.  Also, you don't need the pipe after `sort`.  try this:

```
 ls | sort > results
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do:

```
ls | sort > results
```

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
ls | sort > results
```

`<` is for input redirection, whereas you want the output to be redirected, ie, use `>`. For more info on I/O redirection, read [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Answer (score 1):

You got the redirection wrong, as per the other answers you need:

```
ls | sort > results
```

And, might I ask, why are you using `sort`? `ls` already sorts by name. If you just want the results in one column you can use:

```
ls -1 > results
```

You can also sort by timestamp among other options see `man ls`:

```
ls -1t
```

Or reverse sort any results:

```
ls -1tr
```